# Out of Stack Space when excel is refreshed

Tags: vba, excel, stack, stack-overflow

```
'Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'
'    If IsError(Range("ValTest1").Value) Then
'            Sheets("Market Books (2)").Select
'            Range("HistoricalData").Select
'            Selection.ClearContents
'    else
'       call macro12
'    End If
'
'End Sub
```

I was running below code within a sheet of VBA.  I am getting out of stack message.  The screen is updated every 2 seconds due to API connection.  So it will trigger the code every 2 seconds.  Could you give me a help how I can still clear the content when the API returns error values?  If API returns value, I wanted to trigger some other macro (macro12)

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to some of the reasons for "Out of Stack"

Answer (score 0):

You may be creating multiple *Calculate* events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False

    If IsError(Range("ValTest1").Value) Then
            Sheets("Market Books (2)").Select
            Range("HistoricalData").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
    Else
       Call macro12
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Disable Events during your processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If IsError(Range("ValTest1").Value) Then
            Sheets("Market Books (2)").Select
            Range("HistoricalData").Select

            Call SelectNewCell

    Else
        Call Macro12

    End If

End Sub
```

Basically SelectNewCell() fixes the problem.  It must be unloading the memory space cased by so many repeated selections

I put the SelectNewCell() within the same sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.ScrollArea = "A1:M34"
End Sub
```

Comment: The stack is contigious memory address space that sets up functions. It contains the return address, parameters passed to it, and local variables. Every property or method call is a function underneath. It starts at 1 mb and grows automatically untill it bumps into some memory being used - then it can't grow. Nested functions are on the stack in order called. Recursive functions if too deep can fill up the stack.